# Jenkins executes more than once the bash JDK installation script

Tags: java, bash, jenkins

I have the following script for installing the Java JDK 8 with JCE and Bouncy Castle. Pretty straightforward.

```
wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u101-b13/jdk-8u101-linux-x64.tar.gz" -O jdk-8u101-linux-x64.tar.gz

tar -xvf jdk-8u101-linux-x64.tar.gz

wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jce/8/jce_policy-8.zip" -O jce_policy-8.zip

unzip jce_policy-8.zip

rm -rf jdk1.8.0_101/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar
rm -rf jdk1.8.0_101/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
mv UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8/US_export_policy.jar jdk1.8.0_101/jre/lib/security/
mv UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8/local_policy.jar jdk1.8.0_101/jre/lib/security/

wget "https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-154.jar" -O bcprov-jdk15on-154.jar

mv bcprov-jdk15on-154.jar jdk1.8.0_101/jre/lib/security/

echo "security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider" >> jdk1.8.0_101/jre/lib/security/java.security

rm -rf jdk-8u101-linux-x64.tar.gz
rm -rf jce_policy-8.zip
rm -rf UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8
```

I've created a new almost empty Maven job and I've configured it to use the JDK which is installed automatically by the given script.

I don't know why but the script is getting executed twice which is pretty annoying and takes more time than required.

Any ideas? The issue can be reproduced in an clean installation in Jenkins 2.18 and 1.650 with the default plugins. Should I open an issue in Jenkins JIRA?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've solved the problem putting all the script inside an `if` statement checking if the folder with the JDK exists. Simple.